# Function to check a row in database with session variable not working

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I'm working on a web app, in PHP and AngularJS.

I want to restrict a part of my navbar for users that has a special row. (Like admins)

I made an angularJS function in my controller, which calls a function in my PHP Controller. (I'm working on with MVC and no PHP framework)

The problem is that I pass a variable session in parameter, which the one I can identify my user in my database, and it's not working.

The function is not working. No erros in the logs, no errors in the console, nothing. The "Admin" part of my navbar won't go back if I got the good right to see it.

PHP Function

```
function verifierHabilitation ( $req, $api ){
    if(droitsModificationAdmin( $_SESSION['nni'] ) == "administration") {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I'm calling my function droitsModificationAdmin() to verify the row, and I'm using a variable session in parameter.

AngularJS Function Call in my navbar

```
<li class="nav-item" ng-if="droitsAdmin() == 1" >
    <h2 ng-class="{ 'grdf-ss-title' : isActive('/admin') }" >
       <a class="nav-link" href="#/admin">Admin</a>
    </h2>
</li>
```

Here I'm using ng-if to verify the return of my previous function.

I don't know where the problem is. Do you have any idea ?

EDIT :

Here is all the code I used :

AJS :
In my controller.js

```
$scope.droitsAdmin = function() { factoryDossier.verifierHabilitation(); };
```

In my factory.js

```
verifierHabilitation : function(){

    return $http({
        url: 'controleurs/Controleur-Admin.php'
        ,method: "POST"
        ,data: $.param({
            fonction : 'verifierHabilitation'
        })
        ,headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    });
},
```

PHP:
Controller.php

```
function verifierHabilitation ( $req, $api ){
    if(droitsModificationAdmin( $_SESSION['nni'] ) == "administration") {
        echo "ceci est un test";
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Here I am calling the function which is in the global controller.

Global Controller

```
function droitsModificationAdmin( $nni ){
    $bdd = new Model_Habilitation( PDO_bdd_app() );
    $utilisateur = $bdd->habilitation( $nni );
    return ( $utilisateur[0]['h_habilitation'] );
}
```

Model.php

```
public function habilitation( $nni ){
        $sql = $this->grea_ouest->prepare('SELECT h_habilitation FROM '.$this->table_habilitation.' h WHERE h.h_nni = :nni');
        $sql->execute( array( ':nni' => $nni ) );
        return $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
```

Controleur-Configuration.php

(Sorry the code is in french)

```
<?php

require_once('Controleur-Configuration.php');
require_once('api_rest.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../class/ClassAdmin.php');
require_once(model_url('Model_Admin'));
require_once('Helpers.php');

#############################################################
gestion_session();//Gestion à partir du fichier configuration
#############################################################

$api = new Rest;

try {
    $req = $api->get_request();
    if( function_exists( $req['fonction'] ) ){ $req['fonction']( $req, $api ); } else { throw new Exception('Fonction inexistante'); }
} catch(Exception $e){
    $api->response(array(), 501);
}

/**
 * Retourne les informations d'un admin
 * @param $req array : les données passées en parametres
 * @param $api Rest : l'objet Rest permettant l'interaction avec le client.
 * @return array : les informations du dossier.
 */
function getAdmins( $req, $api ){
    $bdd = new Model_Admin( PDO_bdd_app() );
    try{
        $Admins = $bdd->getAdmins();
        foreach($Admins as $key=>$Admin){ $Admins[$key] = $Admin->json_encode(); }
        $api->response( $Admins, 200);
    } catch(Exception $e){ error_log( $e ); $api->response( "", 500); }
}

/**
 * Retourne les habilitations
 * @param $req array : les données passées en parametres
 * @param $api Rest : l'objet Rest permettant l'interaction avec le client.
 * @return array : les informations du dossier.
 */
function getHabilitations( $req, $api ){
    $bdd = new Model_Admin( PDO_bdd_app() );
    try{
        $Habilitations = $bdd->getHabilitations();
        foreach($Habilitations as $key=>$Habilitation){ $Habilitations[$key] = $Habilitation->json_encode(); }
        $api->response( $Habilitations, 200);
    } catch(Exception $e){ error_log( $e ); $api->response( "", 500); }
}

/**
* Met a jour un habilité
* @param $req array : les données passées en parametres
* @param $api Rest : l'objet Rest permettant l'interaction avec le client.
* @return array : les informations du CA.
* @throws Exception : retourne une erreur 500.
*/
function updateAdmin( $req, $api ){
    $bdd = new Model_Admin( PDO_bdd_app() );
    try {
        if( isset($req['NewAdmin']) ){
            $admin = cast( $req['NewAdmin'], 'Admin' );
        } else { $api->response( array( "erreur" => array(array("Aucunes informations saisies"))), 409); }

            try
            {
                $bdd = new Model_Admin( PDO_bdd_app() );
                $newAdmin = $bdd->updateAdmin( $admin );
                $api->response( array( "dev"=>$newAdmin->json_encode(), "info"=>array("Le développeur a été modifié")), 200);
    } catch( Exception $e ){ error_log( $e ); $api->response( "", 500); }
    } catch( Exception $e ){ error_log( $e ); $api->response( "", 500); }
}

/**
* Change l'habilitation d'un utilisateur
* @param $req array : les données passées en parametres
* @param $api Rest : l'objet Rest permettant l'interaction avec le client.
* @return array : les informations du CA.
* @throws Exception : retourne une erreur 500.
*/
function changerHabilitation ($req, $api){
    $bdd = new Model_Admin( PDO_bdd_app() );
    try{
        $habilitation = $bdd->changerHabilitation( $req['nni'], $req['habilitation'] );
    } catch(Exception $e){
        error_log( $e );
        $api->response( $e, 500);
    }
}

function verifierHabilitation ( $req, $api ){
    if(droitsModificationAdmin( $_SESSION['nni'] ) == "administration") {
        echo "ceci est un test";
        return 1;
    }
}

/**
* Approuve un utilisateur
* @param $req array : les données passées en parametres
* @param $api Rest : l'objet Rest permettant l'interaction avec le client.
* @return array : les informations du CA.
* @throws Exception : retourne une erreur 500.
*/
function approuverUtilisateur ($req, $api){
    $bdd = new Model_Admin( PDO_bdd_app() );
    try{
        $utilisateur = $bdd->approuverUtilisateur( $req['nni'] );
    } catch(Exception $e){
        error_log( $e );
        $api->response( $e, 500);
    }
}

/**
* Refuse un utilisateur
* @param $req array : les données passées en parametres
* @param $api Rest : l'objet Rest permettant l'interaction avec le client.
* @return array : les informations du CA.
* @throws Exception : retourne une erreur 500.
*/
function refuserUtilisateur ($req, $api){
    $bdd = new Model_Admin( PDO_bdd_app() );
    try{
        $utilisateur = $bdd->refuserUtilisateur( $req['nni'] );
    } catch(Exception $e){
        error_log( $e );
        $api->response( $e, 500);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, what is `droitsAdmin` in JS and what it have to do with PHP code your have in your question? Are you trying to execute php function from JavaScript? You're asking about database but no database code in your snippets.

Comment: @jcubic Sorry, I'm not good in explanations. I made a function in AngularJS's Controller, which call a function in an AJS Factory, and this function is calling a PHP Function in the PHP controller. Well that's complicated. In my Model I'm doing a MySQL request, `SELECT h_habilitation FROM '.$this->table_habilitation.' h WHERE h.h_nni = :nni` And "nni" is the session variable

Comment: In general: Clarifications of the question should be added by editing the question. So any new reader does not stumble upon the unclear parts of your question again.

Comment: Looks like you are working on a permission module in which you are restricting user to perform some action. Am I right?

Comment: Functions in `ng-if` expressions should be idempotent and synchronous. Avoid calling asycnchonous functions from the template.

Comment: @rahim.nagori That's right, and I'll use my JS function "droitsAdmin()" to restrict the page only to users which got the right permission.

Comment: Try update your question with examples that will show all the code that is needed to reproduce the same stuff locally. This is not enough If I want to reproduce the issue myself.

Comment: @jcubic No problems, I'm doing it

Comment: You are checking if the user is an admin on the client. You have no guarantee that this check has nit been tampered with and is a unreliable check.

Comment: Could you provide your file `controleurs/Controleur-Admin.php`?

Comment: Of course, I replied

Comment: Sorry to say, but you have a serious security issue in your code! `controleurs/Controleur-Admin.php` blindly calls the function whose name is provided in the param `fonction` and you pass not validated arguments to it. An attacker could spoof those values in the request and exploit that code.

Comment: I know but this application is only internal. Few employees of the company can access it

Answer (score 0):

The $http service does not return a value, it returns a promise from which a value needs to be extracted:

```
$scope.droitsAdmin = function() {
    var promise = factoryDossier.verifierHabilitation();
    return promise.then(function (response) {
        var data = response.data;
        $scope.droitsAdminData = data;
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        throw error;
    });
};
```

There are other problems with your code, but this should give you console messages that will show the problems.

Comment: Thank you, I'll test that !

Answer (score -1):

Okay so as you need some permission module you can do something like this:
Create an Angularjs service to store all the permission values, so you don't have to hit your database again and again, store your permission values in this service at the time of login.
Use your code like this :

```
<div ng-if="permission == 'user'">
    Some content which you want to show to **USER** only.
</div>
<div ng-if="permission == 'user' || permission == 'admin'">
    Some content which you want to show to **USER and ADMIN** both.
</div>
<div ng-if="permission == 'admin'">
    Some content which you want to show to **ADMIN** only.
</div>
```

Looks like you are calling your PHP function from JAVASCRIPT.
**You cannot do this.**
**You have to make an HTTP request (AJAX CALL) to perform this operation.**
Let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: All parts are embedded in the source code in the client and can be viewed by anybody.

Comment: Code updated, I know the way I did is working because all the other functions are as this and are working